# Expand /home partiton (dual booted)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, home-directory

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I found none of the answers to be very explanatory or upvoted enough for an effective solution.

Keeping it short, quite evidently I am running out of space on my `/home` (`sda6`), and have about 197 gigs unused (which I plan to completely dedicate to my ubuntu home assuming it's legal)

I am aware that only logically adjacent partitions can be exchanged memory between, but apparently there is a way using a **live USB** that allows us to do otherwise.

Ps: `sda1` is my windows data drive.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `but apparently there is a way using a live USB that allows us to do otherwise` - No, you must have unallocated space adjecent to the partition you want to grow in size, wether you use a live USB or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Backup everything first.
2. Decide how much capacity you can spare from sda1. Using Windows disk management shrink sda1 by that amount.
3. Boot into the Ubuntu install media. Select the Try Ubuntu option. Open gparted in the Try Ubuntu session.
4. Move each partition (sda3, sda2, sda5, and sda6) except the recovery partition to the left so that the spare space is created in step 2 is adjacent to sda6
5. Expand sda6.

Hope this helps